# How to use Latin Modern font for math with arabic font

Tags: fonts, context, arabic

I want to write arabic document which contain mathematics using `context`, I would like to use Latin Modern font for mathematics (which I use when writing my documents with xelatex).

My question is how to combine arabic font for text  with Latin Modern font for mathematic

**xelatex MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}

كلمة كلمة

$x+y$

\end{document}
```

**Context (Not WE)**

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\setupalign[r2l]  

\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [name:Amiri] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [name:Amiri] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
 \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default]
\stoptypescript 

\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=25mm, width=160mm,
  topspace=15mm, height=265mm,
  header=10mm,footer=10mm,
  headerdistance=2mm
  ]

\setupbodyfont[Arabic,18pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=30pt]

\starttext

كلمة كلمة 

$x+y$

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `math` typeface as well. The following should work (Not tested because I don't have the arabic font):

```
\starttypescript [Arabic]
 \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default]
 \definetypeface [Arabic] [mm] [math]  [modern] [default]
\stoptypescript
```